How to Bypass Microsoft Authenticator Requirement for Apple App Review When Using Only "Sign In with Microsoft"?
I'm developing an app that uses only Sign In with Microsoft for authentication. Due to Microsoft's new policy, Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) via the Microsoft Authenticator app is mandatory after the initial 14-day grace period. While users can skip 2FA for 14 days, they are eventually required to authenticate using the Authenticator app.
The issue arises during the Apple App Review process, where I cannot assist the reviewer in bypassing or completing the 2FA requirement. This prevents Apple from successfully testing the sign-in functionality of my app.
I've attempted to disable 2FA on my account, as some forums suggest, but even after disabling it, the app still prompts for authentication via the Authenticator app.
Has anyone encountered a similar issue during the App Store review process? How can I ensure that the Apple reviewers can sign in without being blocked by the Microsoft 2FA requirement?

You can definitely still have Entra ID accounts without MFA as long as they are not administrators.  You could also use a script with the Graph APIs to delete and recreate your test account prior to each submission so that MFA is still in the grace period.  Finally, in my experience after the initial review Apple often relies on automatic review;  We didn't realise that our test account had been invalid for about 12 months until Apple finally had an issue; We had released many updates in that time.
